# Does Salesforce site support Picklist Field

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I create a Salesforce site in which many fields are displayed except the picklist `Gender`  field when I preview from the visualforce page then it working (picklist field show) Please check the images below.
Image 1 is salesforce site preView.
Image 2 is a visualforce preview.

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

```
<apex:page standardController="individual_customer__c"  showHeader="false" sidebar="false" >
    <apex:form >
        <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    .myClass {   width: 100%;
                    padding: 12px 20px;
                    margin: 8px 0;
                    display: inline-block;
                    border: 1px solid #ccc;
                    border-radius: 4px;
                    height:35px;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                    }
                    .card {
                    background-color:#F8F8F8;
                    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                    transition: 0.3s;
                    width: 700px;
                    height: 500px;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div style="width:800px; height:600px; margin-top:30px;margin-left:300px">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div style="width:100%;text-align: left;height:40px;margin-top:10px; background:#b30059">
                            <p style=" color:white;padding-top:13px;margin-left:10px;font-family: Lucida Console, Courier New, monospace;font-size:18px; text-color:white">
                                
                                <b>My Detail</b>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 60%; margin: 0px auto;">
                            <table style="margin-top:10px; margin:center; width:100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:100px">
                                        First Name
                                        
                                        </td>
                                    <td>                           
                                        <apex:inputField id="InputFieldId" onblur="restrictCurrencyValue('{!$Component.InputFieldId}')"  value="{!individual_customer__c.Name}" required="true"  styleClass="myClass"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:100px">
                                        Date of Birth
                                        
                                       </td>
                                    <td>                           
                                        <apex:inputField value="{!individual_customer__c.Date_of_Birth__c}"
                                                         required="true" style="  width: 100%;
                                                                                padding: 12px 20px;
                                                                                margin: 8px 0;
                                                                                display: inline-block;
                                                                                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                                                                                border-radius: 4px;
                                                                                height:35px;
                                                                                box-sizing: border-box;"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:100px">
                                      Middle Name
                                        
                                        </td>
                                    <td>                           
                                        <apex:inputField value="{!individual_customer__c.Name}" required="true"  styleClass="myClass"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:100px">
                                        Family Name
                                        
                                        </td>
                                    <td>                           
                                        <apex:inputField value="{!individual_customer__c.Name}" required="true"  styleClass="myClass"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:100px">
                                       Mobile Phone
                                        
                                        </td>
                                    <td>                           
                                        <apex:inputField value="{!individual_customer__c.Name}" required="true"  styleClass="myClass"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:100px">
                                        Home/Work PHone Number
                                        
                                        </td>
                                    <td>                           
                                        <apex:inputField value="{!individual_customer__c.Name}" required="true"  styleClass="myClass"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:100px">
                                        Gender
                                        
                                        </td>
                                    <td>       
                               
                                       <apex:inputField value="{!individual_customer__c.Gneder__c}"/>
                                       
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </body>
        </html>
    </apex:form>
    
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function restrictCurrencyValue(fieldId) {
    
        var amountValue = document.getElementById(fieldId).value;
        var enteredAmount = amountValue;
    alert("Function called" + enteredAmount);
}
    </script>
    
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I've downvoted because you're continuing to add irrelevant tags to your question. Tags are meant to describe what the question is about and help people determine if the question is relevant to them or something that is likely to be within their knowledge (for people who answer questions).

Answer (score 1):

Visualforce enforces Field Level Security for all fields. This means a user needs to be able to edit a field to have the page allow editing. When viewing from a Site, you are logged in by default as a Guest User, which is a different profile. You need to make the field editable for this profile. Go to your Site, click on Public Access Settings, then go to the Object Settings section, then to the object, and then edit the permissions for the field. You'll then be able to edit the field on the Site.

Comment: go to `` Public Access Settings``  then  ``custom object permission``   there is only ``read and create`` checkbox is check  ``edit`` is inactive  OWD for that object is  ``Public read/write`` how can I check the ``edit`` box?